# xamarin System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception

Tags: c#, android, mysql, database, xamarin

I'm working on a database connection with the entity framework in xamarin but when it is running there is an error that appears like the image. anyone can help?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZAGY.png)

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoU0V.png)

Comment: Do the following in the App.config file,Hope it will help you out:
1.Put the `connectionStrings` element is after the `configSections` element.
2.Put the startup element after the `connectionStrings` element.

Comment: @Dungeon not working. in my project web.config not app.config

Comment: can you post entire web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Try These:

- This weird error happens, when you play around with different
  versions of `EntityFramework` versions in `Nuget` Packages. Removing the
  references to Entity Framework and installing the latest version of
  Entity Framework from `NuGet` fixed the issue. It recreates all the
  required entries for you during install.
- Change by `defaultConnectionFactory` to be `SqlConnectionFactory` instead of the default.
- Remove the `provider` under the `entityFramwork` section.

Hope it helps! 
Thanks!